# Search keyword with values in arraylist in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android development. I have created a search widget in `ActionBar`. Now I have to search my keyword with value stored in `ArrayList`. How can I get value of that searched keyword in a variable? Please give me some sample code for that.

Comment: Like String searchTerm = searchWidget.getText().toString(); ?

Comment: You have to show some code, please.

Comment: Hey i have written simple some codes for search widget in action bar and if i enter any keyword,it has to be compared with array list value and display result if it matches  @joao2fast4u

Comment: Ok, could you post your code? Where are you defining your search widget?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I want to create my search widget in action bar. code is too big,not able to post..kindly help me if you can

Comment: What class are you using for your widget?

Comment: You can use SearchView for that. See this link: http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: @joao2fast4u i am not able to post my code here.is there any other way to send message to you?

Comment: @user3575446 do you want to search any item using any button click or just text change?

Comment: @shweta_jain, hi,if i write anything in search widget the keyword will be searched with arrailist value and is it matches result will be displayed

Comment: arraylist is coming from server ? or do you have any static array list?

Comment: not from server,in java class you have to create one arraylist and have to compare search keyword  @shweta_jain

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an OnQueryTextListener to your searchView. Like this:

```
    //listener to when the user changes the text
    _searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        boolean _first = true;
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String str) {
            //do you arraylist filtering here
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); //your arraylist, that you will filter
            for(String arrayItem:arrayList){
                if(arrayItem.contains(str)){
                    //add this item to your new list
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Then you just have to refresh your `listAdapter` with the new filtered array.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet

actionbar_serch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/action_header"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

package com.example.demosearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
Button btn_search;

ArrayList<String> item_array;

EditText  edit_search;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    item_array=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        item_array.add("item"+i);
    }

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_serch);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    btn_search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);


    edit_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_search);

        edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String item=s.toString();

         for(int i=0;i<item_array.size();i++)
            {
                if(item.equals(item_array.get(i)))
                {
                    Log.e("Search item position is=", ""+i);
                    break;
                }
            }

    }
});


}
```

}

Hope this helps you!!!!!
If it is not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: what i have to write in action_header.xml? I have created a search widget in action bar.

Comment: what is action_header.xml ? is it your action bar layout?

Comment: you have mentioned in actionbar_serch.xml
 android:background="@drawable/action_header"

Comment: action_header just an image for set in background of actionbar layout so you can put any image or just leave it

Comment: check my edited answer - i put textchangelistener on edit text

Comment: Hi shweta, i think my requirement is not clear to you. Are you there?

Comment: May be i didn't understand your requirement can you elaborate what you wannna do?

Comment: I have created a search widget in actionbar.For that i created a xml under menu folder.In JAVA class i have to create an arraylist with some strings in it.Now if i enter any keyword in search widget,that will be compared with arraylist values.If keyword matches then result will be displayed,otherwise it will show no item found.This is my requirement.If you have any doubt let me know or i can send my files to you.

Comment: So please create an XML in to your res/layout folder i already post an xml for actionbar_search.xml.. then try my code it will be work.  in my code i put position of item so you just put that item value in to any textview for example - yourtextview.setText(item_array.get(i))

Comment: I tried your code but in emulator it is showing unfortunately stopped.
can i send my files to you anyhow?

Comment: Hi shweta, did you get my mail?